# Separate the luminance from the chrominance in an image

Tags: image-processing, color

My goal is to separate a full-color image into its luminance and chrominance ("color") components and display them as two images:  1) a black and white image (for the luminance) and 2) a color image (for the chrominance).

It would appear that the proper color space for this separation would be CMYK (cyan-magenta-yellow-black), as this separates the black from the others:

[image: color separate]

This gives me four component images.  The last of which is the luminance (like a grayscale) image... half of what I need.

But how do I combine the first three channels to obtain a colored image that has no luminance component... i.e., appears in color but is of uniform lightness?

Comment: What not use something like `LAB` as your color space? That has a luminance built into it

Comment: I'll try that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L3Hc.png"]
```

[image]

You can also use [`ImageMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMultiply.html) or [`ImageApply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageApply.html) as follows:

```
ImageMultiply[ColorConvert[img, "CMYK"], {1, 1, 1, 0}]
```

[image]

```
ImageApply[{1, 1, 1, 0} # &, ColorConvert[img, "CMYK"]]
```

[image]

```
% == %%
```

> True

```
ImageMultiply[ColorConvert[img, "CMYK"], 1 - {1, 1, 1, 0}]
```

[image]

```
ImageApply[(1 - {1, 1, 1, 0}) # &, ColorConvert[img, "CMYK"]]
```

[image]

```
% == %%
```

> True

Answer (score 6):

Here's something that uses the [`"LAB"` colorspace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LABColor.html):

```
butterfly = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L3Hc.png"], "LAB";
```

To kill the color channels:

```
ImageMultiply[butterfly, {1, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

Or to put everything on max "lightness" (an approximate luminance):

```
ColorCombine[
 Prepend[
  ColorSeparate[butterfly][[2 ;;]],
  ConstantImage[1, ImageDimensions[butterfly]]
  ],
 "LAB"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks (+1)... but I think kglr basically solved it (first).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yeah not an issue. Just figured it'd be good to have a `LAB` solution out there since the `L` is suppose to approximate how people perceive luminance. `LUV` would likely work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out:

[image]

This re-combines the CMYK channels, but with the black channel effectively set to 0.

[image]

Comment: does  `ImageMultiply[ ColorConvert[img, "CMYK"], {1, 1, 1, 0}]` give the same result?

Comment: also `ImageApply[{1, 1, 1, 0} # &, ColorConvert[img, "CMYK"]]`?